# Animating an image to the Centre when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I've seen this effect in so many modal galleries these days that when the browser is resized the image smoothly animates to centre and not just in a jerk.
Now I've made a fiddle to add an image to centre and also added a css transition but somehow it still jerks after browser resizing.
please tell me where I am doing this wrong.
thanks.
here is the fiddle
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hbU7d/)

```
.fullImages {
margin: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 133;
border: 3px solid black;
max-height: 78%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
margin-top: 33px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.55s ease;
```

}

Here is an example  click on any image and resize the browser to see the modal image animate to center.
[Lightbox Example](http://ilightbox.net/)

Comment: In what browser did you experience this problem?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean

Comment: http://ilightbox.net/

Comment: do you have your problem with the buttons?

Comment: @LajosArpad No not the buttons. See my Fiddle in post, i am not able to (smoothly) animate image to center when browser resizes.

Comment: I think so that you want your image to be looking same even when the browser get resized..Is it so??

Comment: @MiteshJain image centering is fine with resizing, but i want it to be smoothly centered and not with a jerk.